# Dynamically created elements and click handlers cause memory leak in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, onclick

The script is very long, so I'll try to explain rather than paste all of it. Edit: Looks like I do need to show a little more.

A few times every second I update an UL with new content (call updateDomTree). The DOM tree represents elements inside CKEditor.

```
function updateDomTree(editor) {
    var selection = editor.getSelection();
    var jqElements = $(document.createElement('div'));
    var editorData = editor.document.getBody();
    var kids = editorData.getChildren();

    // Gather LI to represent Editor content DOM element hierarchy
    for (var i = 0, len = kids.count(); i < len; i++) {
        jqElements.append(HandleNode(kids.getItem(i), selectedElement, editor));
    }

    var domUL = document.createElement('ul');
    domUL.id = "dom";
    var jqUL = $(domUL).append(liElements);
    $(document.getElementById('dom')).replaceWith(jqUL);
}

// This is a recursive function, but it has no other issues than the memory leak
// If I comment out the click event, it works fine. 
// The **obj** variable is why I don't use the "delegation" method.
function HandleNode(obj, selection, editor) {
    // do other stuff, handle recursion etc.
    liElement.on('click', function(e) {
        editor.getSelection().selectElement( obj );
        editor.focus();
        editor.getSelection().scrollIntoView();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); 
    return liElement;
}
```

Now in IE9, the memory usage starts to climb rapidly. If I comment out the click handler, the memory leak goes away but then I have no functionality. How would I go around this issue?

Alternate explanation: #dom is a UL visual representation of a DOM structure and I need the click event to reference the element, that is why I need the object reference during click event handler creation. When the underlying DOM changes, the UL representation should reflect that change, that is why the rapid updates.

Comment: You should use delegation here. This will avoid creating many handlers and btw should avoid memory leak

Comment: i wonder .. howz you li click working as you are not delegating it to static parent container....i think even your li click event is not working for dynamically generated li.. check it out

Comment: @bipen as i understand it, OP creates a new handler for each LI

Comment: Yeah I do create a new handler for each of them and it does work aside from the memory leak. @roasted - how would I implement delegation in this situation? I don't really know how to, do you have an example?

Comment: hmmm!!! i guess the handler will work only for elements that is present in a document when it was called.. :)....

Comment: Can you post the code of your handler ? A blind guess : the leak comes from some sort of circular reference from the code of the handler.

Comment: I tried to add more details @LeGEC - hopefully this is clearer now!

Comment: @bipen Yes, and that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating a new handler each time you create a `li` element, you can use event delegation and bind one single handler to the `ul` itself :

```
// when you create the list :
$('#dom').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    // do some cool stuff
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// instead of creating a new ul,
// replace thhe existing ul's content
$('#dom').empty().append(liElements);
```

---

If you need to store custom data for each node, try using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function :

```
$(liElement).data('obj', obj);
```

You can then access it from the handler :

```
$('#dom').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var obj = $(this).data('obj');
    ...
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

With this design, javascript won't have to maintain a live closure to keep access to the `obj` variable. I'm not 100% sure it will blow your memory leak away, you will have to test and see.

Comment: I need a custom object reference when I'm creating the click handler, so I can't do this - or can I? In the question: "I can't do a $('li').click(...) because I need an object reference that is available just during element creation." - the object I'm representing with the UL is a CKEditor object, and I need a reference to it in the handler. That's why I could not bind to it like this. Or do you have a suggestion how I could?

Comment: I do not understand your "reference" part. Can you show the code you use to access this reference ? I'm pretty sure there is a way for you to get the reference from the handler's code using `$(this).ckeditor()` or `$(this).find('.ckeditor')` or something similar.

Comment: Ok, I added that part as well. (obj) is not a DOM object, it's a CKEditor object with some custom stuff that make it possible to use for the basis a selection.

Comment: Using .data() to save the object reference worked and it looks like it also got rid of the memory leak! I am overflowing with joy, yet again learning how to fail less, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Delegate it to UL's level, just set it until UL element is DOM available:

```
$('#dom').on('click','li', function(e) {
    // do some cool stuff
    e.stopPropagation(); //stopPropagation couldn't give you expected result depending why you need to stop bubbles and at which level, check it.
});
```

Comment: In the question I said "I can't do a $('li').click(...) because I need an object reference that is available just during element creation." -- I need the object reference, so I can't do this. I can't get a reference to the DOM element in a handler like this. The DOM I am displaying comes from a CKEditor, and I need it's custom object and not just a DOM reference. Or could I somehow do it otherwise?

Comment: Also, `stopPropagation()` at the moment does what I expect it to do and stops the click event from bubbling, how would it not work?

Comment: As delegate target, use the closest static DOM element present in DOM at any time (.eg you could use document but this is not the preferred one). As using delegation the event occurs at delegate target level (here #dom), if you want to stop bubbles for not fired e.g a click handler for TR, this won't work. For anything at level upper TABLE, would work. Otherwise, you have to filter event using event.target or maybe event.currentTarget (not to confond with event.delegateTarget).

Comment: I would just go around that issue by giving the LI elements a class and binding to `$('.liElement').on(...)`, wouldn't that work? In any case, I would not have the element reference at this point, so I can't  use this method AFAIK. At least I have no idea how to use this method. I did not know this was called delegation, I've just called it event binding :).

Comment: If you use your syntax with .on(), all elements dynamically added after handler been read won't fired event. This is the purpose of using delegation. To make it works using class in any case even DOM not ready, use this: `$(document).on('click','.liElement', function(e) {...});`  But then, stopPropagation wouldn't work, filter using `event.target` e.g or any other way depending what you wish. I'm sorry, i don't know your code, i don't know what you are looking for...

Comment: That's interesting. Well, if I can solve the object reference issue I can totally change to using this method. I already use a bunch of `$(document).on('click', '.cellThree', function(evt) {...});` on the page, but I never had them nested so I never ran into the issue before - thanks for the tip!